# Mariadb galera cluster init unsucessfully

Tags: mariadb, galera

I have a problem when I try to initial a mariadb galera cluster with three nodes(mariadb1,mariadb2,mariadb3).The problem is the second nodes initialization can not be sucessfully,it raise this error in the background:

2017-09-05 11:25:33 140647619090176 [ERROR] WSREP: gcs/src/gcs_group.cpp:gcs_group_handle_join_msg():736: Will never receive state. Need to abort.
<<<<

Comment: the node2's parameter setting just like this：[root@mariadb3 mysql]# cat /etc/my.cnf.d/server.cnf |grep -v "#"

[server]


[mysqld]
[galera]
wsrep_on=ON
wsrep_provider=/usr/lib64/galera/libgalera_smm.so
wsrep_cluster_address=gcomm://192.168.122.131
wsrep_cluster_name='galera'
binlog_format=row
default_storage_engine=InnoDB
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode=2
wsrep_node_address='192.168.122.132'
wsrep_sst_auth=sst:root
wsrep_sst_method=rsync
wsrep_slave_threads=2
bind-address=192.168.122.132

[embedded]

[mariadb]

[mariadb-10.1]

Comment: make edit so it looks like question